# How to create a c++ constructor with 2d arrays as parameters

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, constructor

I need to have a class with a 2d array used to store places on a board. But I can't make a constructor that makes this properly sets up this field.

this is the code I get a array type un assignable error, the cell is a typedefStruct

```
Board::Board(waterCraft * listOfCraft, cell gameBoard[][10]) {
    this->listOfCraft = listOfCraft;
    this->gameBoard = gameBoard;
}
```

Comment: Show how the class is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If Board::gameBoard is of type `cell**` i.e. pointer to a pointer: `cell** gameBoard` or `cell* gameBoard[]`
2. If Board::gameBoard is of type `cell[10][10]` (assuming no. of rows is 10) i.e. a 2d array:

```
constexpr int R = 10, C = 10;
Board::Board(waterCraft * listOfCraft, cell gameBoard[R][C]) {
    this->listOfCraft = listOfCraft;
    std::copy(&gameBoard[0][0], &gameBoard[0][0] + R*C, &this->gameBoard[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing common with a two-dimensional array with elements of the type cell.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow care to explain? Read the title.

Comment: What to explain? Do you know what is the two-dimensional array?

Comment: @heWiseBro  Now at least this is better though the answer looks irrelevant because it is unknown how the class is defined.